# ImportError PyQt5 in PyCharm on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, importerror, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I install PyQt5 and PyCharm on Linux (python 3.5.2),  but after this easy code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWebEngineView()
window.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://google.com"))
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have this Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/Browser/BrowserQt5.py", line 4, in 
>       from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
>
> ImportError: libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to fix this Error?

Comment: i think you should install `libqt5webkit5` package

Comment: but i want to use QWebEngine(on Chromium core) not WebKit core

Comment: ok, but as you can see from the error message you are missing a shared library that should be provided by `libqt5webkit5` package

Comment: @mic4ael That package provides QtWebKit, not QtWebEngine.

Comment: @VolArt What Linux distribution are you using? QtWebEngine was only added in Qt 5.4, so it seems like you're running something older?

Comment: Install qt5-webengine and reinstall pyqt5. Works. 
'import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
window.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://youtube.com"))
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())'